# Distribution and expectation of Poisson random variable with gamma distributed mean

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

**Question**

Suppose X ~ Pois($\lambda$), where the mean parameter $\lambda$ itself is a random variable with pdf

$$g(\lambda;\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\beta ^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \lambda^{\alpha - 1} \exp(-\beta \lambda)$$

and $\lambda, \alpha, \beta > 0$

Find the distribution of X and compute $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

**My working**

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(X=x) & = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X = x \mid \lambda = \lambda) \mathbb{P}(\lambda = \lambda) \ d\lambda \\
&  = \int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\lambda^{\alpha - 1} e^{-\beta \lambda} \ d\lambda \\ 
&  = \frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{(x+\beta)^{\alpha -1}}
\end{aligned}$$

Now I am stuck as I am not sure if my answer for distribution of  X is correct. If I am on the right path, how should I proceed to compute $\mathbb{E}(X)$?

Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: The question states that conditioned on $\lambda$, $X$ has Poisson distribution - but in your work you've written that it has exponential distribution.

Comment: @Math1000 Oh, thanks for pointing that out! What a silly mistake! I've worked the question out again and I just wanted to check whether $X \sim NegBin \left( \alpha, \frac{1}{1+\beta} \right)$ would be correct?